# decompose web application war file into different components

Tags: web-applications, architecture, war

How do I split a huge war file into multiple components (multiple war files). Are there any best practices around this?

Answer (score 0):

How huge is huge?  And why has this become a problem for you?

So the pieces will be separate services?

Just one way to do it: get a shovel and start digging.

*Why* are the WARs so huge?  Are there a lot of JARs in the WEB-INF/lib?  The problem you'll have is dependencies.  If every separate WAR requires all the JARs, you'll have lots of huge WARs instead of one because you'll have to duplicate the JARs.

If the .class files in the WEB-INF/classes folder depend on each other, you won't be able to separate them.

Comment: The pieces will be separate services. This needs to be separated as separate components to facilitate easy testing, deploy them independently. The .class files in WEB-INF/classes will be independent of each other as they are separate, unique components. Most of the jars will be the same and they need to be duplicated in the war files